# Models bleeding together in models.py?

Tags: python, django, model, django-forms

In Django I'm trying to write a ModelForm for a ContactForm and when I try to load the page containing the form it says that it doesn't exist. Then when I try to render the other form I had previously written it says that

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'CashtextsForm' object has no attribute 'subject'
```

'Subject' is a field in the form that I was trying to render in ContactForm. So is there some certain order I have to list them in models.py? Here's that code:

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Cashtexts(models.Model):
    cashTexts = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True) #change me to a website filter
    superPoints = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)#chance to "superPoints _Username"
    varolo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    swagbucks = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    neobux = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    topline = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Paidviewpoint = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    cashcrate = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cashcode

class Contact(models.Model):
    sender = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    message = models.TextField()

class CashtextsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cashtexts

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject


class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

I previously had them arranged as Model-Modelform, Model-Modelform but [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)it shows them as the way I now currently have them.

Also Is there any advantages to write just forms? Right now I'm more comfortable writing model forms over forms(I dont imagine they are much differnt) but if  I only wrote model forms would I be missing out on features? So is there anything I missed on how t write multiple forms in models.py or did I have them written worng? or can i not create them via the command syncdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__unicode__(self)` method should be part of your `Contact` class

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    sender = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject
```

It doens't make sense inside `CashtextsForm` as that does not "know" a `subject` attribute.

Comment: alright i changed that up and the CashtextsForm works now but it still says contact form doesn't exist. any idea why it isnt being created?

Comment: NameError at /contact/
global name 'ContactForm' is not defined

Comment: Are you sure that you properly import ContactForm inside your views.py?

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about the seperate import statement up top.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your form really does not have `subject`, just remove `__unicode__` definition and everything will be ok.

This is because of declarative style of django code. If you want to inspect your objects use `pdb` module and `dir` builtin.

You will use ModelForm subclasses almost every time, but sometimes you will need a form which can not be built from model. In this case django will help you to describe such form and to use form clean and field validation.

Answer (score 0):

the subject field is defined in the model and not in the modelform, since a modelform can be initialized without a model instance it is not safe to do something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.instance.subject
```

What you can do (but I do not really see the point of doing this):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    if getattr(self, 'instance') is not None:
        return self.instance.subject
    return super(CashtextsForm, self).__unicode__()
```